# ResponseListener isnt updating my class variable

Tags: java, android, response

I have a `ResponseListener` which gets some user data from the web. I put the listener in a separate function named `getUserDataFromWeb()`..

I want for test purposes to toast some responded values .. in this example a postcode. When i want to toast the postcode it only works inside the responseListener but not in the `onCreate()` Method after it should have actually updated the class variable `"postcode"` .. in my logic

I tried to toast the postcode in the `onStart()` Method but it was still null

My `onCreate()` Method looks like this:

```
    username = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_USERNAME);
    getUserDataFromWeb(username);
    Toast.makeText(this, postcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // when i toast at this point, the postcode is null...
```

The function looks like following:

```
public void getUserDataFromWeb(String username){

        Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject JSONResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = JSONResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){

                            postcode = JSONResponse.getString(Constants.KEY_POSTCODE);
                             // When i toast the postcode at this place it works

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        UserDataRequest userDataRequest = new UserDataRequest(username,listener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(userDataRequest);

    }
```

Could you help me out why the postcode class variable isnt set after `getUserdataFromWeb()`?

Comment: It looks like your `getUserdataFromWeb` only initiates the request -- it doesn't wait for it to finish. Whatever you need the postcode for, you need to do it inside the listener.

Comment: This is the expected way to work. You are using a callback, data will be available inside the callback, `onResponse`, so you have to do your work inside the `onResponse` method.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. But I want to pass the class variables e.g. the responses to other fragments afterwards. i find it tricky now to do a workaround for that because one Fragment should already be loaded in the onCreate() Method with the postcode ... (which is null at this point). Is there a simple way to fix that?

Comment: create this fragment inside the `onResponse` method, there is no other workaround.

Comment: Alternatively you could play with threads threads, e.g. create a monitor object, put the thread on wait for it after the queueu.add line, and notify it inside the listener. However I don't think this is better (or even good) solution than what @pleft said

Comment: Okay thank you all.